# Is it good practice to have 2 or more tables with the same columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a web-app that lets users search for restaurants and cafes. Since I currently have no data other than their type to differentiate the two, I have two options on storing the list of eateries.

1. Use a single table for both restaurants and cafes, and have an enum (text) column stating if an entry is a restaurant or cafe.
2. Create two separate tables, one for restaurants, and one for cafes.

I will never need to execute a query that collects data from both, so the only thing that matters to me I guess is performance. What would you suggest as the better option for PostgreSQL?

Comment: In your case, option #2 would be a bit faster (especially over time)...  in your code you would determine which table to pull from dynamically.

Comment: Option 2 is a bad idea. Use option 1. That is a properly normalized model and  you will have lot less problems in the future. "*I will never need to execute a query that collects data from both*" - that's very hard to believe. What if a use wants to search for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical database modeling would lend itself to a single table.  The main reason is **maintainability**.  If you have two tables with the same columns and your client decides they want to add a column, say hours of operation.  You now have to write two sets of code for creating the column, reading the new column, updating the new column, etc.  Also, what if your client wants you to start tracking bars, now you need a third table with a third set of code.  It gets messy quick.  It would be better to have two tables, a data table (say Establishment) with most of the columns (name, location, etc.) and then a second table that's a "type" table (say EstablishmentType) with a row for Restaurant, Cafe, Bar, etc.  And of course a foreign key linking the two.  This way you can have "X" types and only need to maintain a single set of code.

There are of course exceptions to this rule where you may want separate tables:

1. Performance due to a HUGE data set.  (It depends on your server, but were talking at least hundreds of thousands of rows before it should matter in Postgres).  If this is the reason I would suggest [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) to keep much of the proper maintainability while speeding up performance.
2. Cafes and Restaurants have two completely different sets of functionality in your website.  If the entirety of your code is saying if Cafe, do this, if Restaurant, do that, then you already have two sets of code to maintain, with the added hassle of `if` logic in your code.  If that's the case, two separate tables is a much cleaner and logical option.

Comment: "Hundreds of thousands" of rows is **not** considered huge these days. Hundreds of **millions** would be.

Comment: Even if there are two sets of functionality in the code, a single table would be best for the reasons you state. If you wanted two data sources, a Cafe view and a Restaurant view could be added. Triggers could even allow for DML through the views. No need to sacrifice maintainability or data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I chose to use 2 separate tables, as I really will never need to search for both at the same time, and this way I can expand a single table in the future if I need to add another data field specific to cafes, for example.